# Do we need links to all the trilogy and friends on the footer on a cooking site?

Tags: feature-request

I think not.

The parent site should be listed more prominently on the footer and maybe only leave the link to api (if the api will work on this site) and area51.

Comment: Just to be clear, the API works on all stackexchange sites.

Answer (score 3):

As the topics become more and more unrelated, simple footer links seem a bit pointless. Right now I guess a lot of us are coming from SO, but down the line each new site should have its own distinct set to users too who may not know (or want to know) anything about programming, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's nice to know that we are part of a larger "family". But I don't really like how the real sites (like stackoverflow and serverfault) are mixed in with all the stuff surrounding them (like api and careers). So I guess I would prefer a redesign of the whole footer.

Comment: My point exactly. I think there should be a hub to talk about the family as a whole, because stackoverflow's main page doesn't tell you that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking forward to 'migrate to stackoverflow' as a close reason for someone asking for instructions for their (ahem) food processor.